# Can't overwrite UIButton options programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Fixed. I had to clear the background image of the button in IB.

---

I have two buttons in my view that should use different images based on if statements. I created the buttons in IB(and set their size,constraints), but I would like to change their appearance in the `viewDidLoad`. I made a method to handle the variations, but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I run the app I can log the proper NSLog, but nothing change. It seems my `setImage: forState:` methods can't overwrite the storyboard option. Do anybody has an idea what did I wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setButtonLayout];
}

- (void) setButtonLayout {

    if ([[PFUser currentUser][@"status"] isEqualToString:@"active"]) {

        [self.bttn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.bttn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [self.bttn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.bttn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        NSLog(@"1. BUTTON");
    }
    if ([[PFUser currentUser][@"status"] isEqualToString:@"inactive"]) {

        [self.bttn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.bttn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [self.bttn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"04-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.bttn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"04-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
         NSLog(@"2. BUTTON");
    }
}
```

Comment: are the images added to the right target?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yes, but I got it, the predefined image was 01-normal.png in IB, I deleted it and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your initialization from the viewWillLoad method to the viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: Thanks, but fortunately I got it. I had to delete the image name in IB.